# How to install a python script as a service ignoring CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT?

Tags: python, windows, service

I am working on a piece of script, or software of you may, that should stay working on all times, even when user is logged off from Windows. I will be compiling the script with py2exe.
I wish to install the .exe as a service, which will ignore the CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT signal which Windows sends when an user is logging off.
I saw some similar asked questions about this, but none applies to what I actually need. Most of them refer to use the python interpreter , and I will be using a py2exe version of the .py script.

Any simple skeleton from where I can get any pointers on how to do it ? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, but I believe that as of Windows Vista this is no longer an issue due to service session isolation.  That is, your service should never receive CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT.  So, unless you still need to support XP, you probably don't need to do anything.

Comment: @HarryJohnston do you have a technical term / reference for "service session isolation"? I can't find any useful hits on MSDN.

Comment: Got it - [Session 0 isolation](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx)